# Facebook PHP SDK Problems

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have problems with facebook SDK, I use this code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
       'appId'  => 'MY_API_KEY',
       'secret' => 'MY_API_SECRET',
       'cookie' => true,
));

 $fql = "My fql query";

 $response = $facebook->api(array(
     'method' => 'fql.query',
     'query' =>$fql,
 ));
 print_r($response);
```

Works fine, but after a while returns an error like: "*Uncaught CurlException: 3: No URL set!*"

That problem appear for few minute (5-10 minutes) and after that works again. The big problem is that error appear few times at hour, somebody know how can I fix that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have set the default responseURL  .

May be this is cause

example :- php codes

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

hope this solves the problem .

Comment: I use it without requestiong to user to authenticate application on facebook (and I can't change that). Works well, but after a while return error and then works well again. What can be wrong here? Maybe something with cookie or cache or something like that. Anyway, thank you for your help.